# How to deserialize the following xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I would like to use `XmlSerializer` for deserialize the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<General>
  <Component>
    <Foo>Foo value1</Foo>
    <Bar>Bar value1</Bar>
  </Component>
  <Component>
    <Foo>Foo value2</Foo>
    <Bar>Bar value2</Bar>
  </Component>
  <Component>
    <Foo>Foo value3</Foo>
    <Bar>Bar value3</Bar>
  </Component>
  <Component>
    <Foo>Foo value4</Foo>
    <Bar>Bar value4</Bar>
  </Component>
</General>
```

how should i organize the classes for the deserialization?

**EDIT:**
This is what i tried:

```
public class General
{
    public List<Component> Component { get; set; }
}

public class Component
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Artifact { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Boiling it should do the trick.

Comment: Add `XmlElement` to `Name` and `Artifact`

Answer (score 1):

See the `General` class. I changed the list's name to `Components` and decorated it with  `XmlElement` attribute.

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(General));
var g = (General)ser.Deserialize(yourStream);
```

---

```
public class General
{
    [XmlElement("Component")]    
    public List<Component> Components { get; set; }
}


public class Component
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but any type inside other type should be marked as `[Serializable]` for `XmlSerializer` to work.

Comment: @Sinatr OK I am correcting. `Serializable` attribute is used only by BinaryFormatter. XmlSerializer doesn't use it. So no need for it. (BTW I posted this code after verifying it worked)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
public class Component
{
     public string Foo {get;set;}
     public string Bar {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this is going to help with the problem.You may need to add little more details.

Comment: The question is: "how should i organize the classes?" and not "how should I deserialize?"

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help you with this Code. Create a new projekt and debug it with this code. Don't forget to add your `XML-Data` into the `debug-folder`. Show in the `xreader.Name Value` to understand what you have to do. I do not know the structure of your components, so i cant help you more. If you show it me I can help more

```
        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        XmlTextReader xreader = new XmlTextReader("YourXML.xml");
        string elem = "";
        while (xreader.Read()) //Read per line (and ?Withspace? (Pls correct me here))
        {
            switch (xreader.NodeType) //Is the line a Element(<General>;<Component>;<Foo>;<Bar>) or Text(value1)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    if (xreader.Name.ToString().Contains("Foo"))
                        elem = xreader.Name;
                    else if (xreader.Name.ToString().Contains("Bar"))
                        elem = xreader.Name;
                    break;

                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    {
                        if (elem == "Foo")
                        {
                            string value1 = xreader.Value;
                        }
                        else if (elem == "Bar")
                        {
                            string value2 = xreader.Value;
                        }
                    }
                    break;


            }
        }
        xreader.Close();
    }
```

PS: Please correct my grammar